How to use RAW Data Type in Flink SQL?
I'm trying to read Avro data with complex schema in Kafka topic. I have following schema:
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "MyAvroData",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "name",
      "type": "long"
    },
    {
      "name": "age",
      "type": "long"
    },
    {
      "name": "content",
      "type": [
        {
          "type": "record",
          "name": "kinda_data_field",
          "fields": [
            {
              "name": "a",
              "type": "int"
            },
            {
              "name": "b",
              "type": ["null", "int"]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "record",
          "name": "kinda_another_field",
          "fields": [
            {
              "name": "stuff",
              "type": "long"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "record",
          "name": "third_field",
          "fields": [
            {
              "name": "one",
              "type": "float"
            },
            {
              "name": "two",
              "type": "float"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

When I'm converting json schema with AvroSchemaConverter to SQL DataTypes I have following SQL schema :
`name` BIGINT NOT NULL,
`age` BIGINT NOT NULL,
`content` RAW('java.lang.Object', ?) NOT NULL

Obviously content RAW('java.lang.Object', ?) NOT NULL not working throwing an exception ParseException: Encountered "?".
My questions is:

How I can read my data using Flink SQL Client ?
What Data type should I use ?

Any help will be appreciated
